# Simpler way to do repeated `back back series`

Tags: series, rebol, red

Sometimes, I tend to do `next next a` (repeatedly) to get at a particular element.
This works well when you need 2 or less traversals.
However, it gets cumbersome pretty soon. A loop is too much overhead for this simple case.

Fortunately you can do `at series pos` in some cases if you know the position.

When it comes to removing the redundancy for the reverse function, a.k.a `back`, this doesn't work as well tho.

Preferably, I want to do something like `at`, but relative to the current position in the series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`skip` allows you to move forwards or backwards from the current position in the series.

```
>> series: [ 1 2 3 4 5 6]
== [1 2 3 4 5 6]

>> series: skip series 2
== [3 4 5 6]

>> series: skip series 3
== [6]

>> series: skip series -3
== [3 4 5 6]
```